# How do you get the last 3 secret cases in another case solved?

Tags: another-case-solved

I've practically completed the game and only have secret cases left to do. What i find strange is that i have found all secret cases in the 5 chapters, but i have only 7/10 secret cases uncovered...

Anyone know how to get the remaining 3 secret cases?

Answer (score 1):

If you 'Like' the game on Facebook it will add 1 case